# Subscription ID always 0 for onProgramAccountChange

Tags: subscription

I am using node js with @solana/web3.js.

I have a connection established like this:

```
const userConnection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(endPoint, {commitment: 'confirmed', wsEndpoint: wssEndPoint});
```

and I am subscribing for notifications like this:

```
 let subscriptionId = await userConnection.onProgramAccountChange
  (
    PROGRAM_ID,
    async (updatedAccountInfo) => 
    {
      console.log("Subscription processing triggered...");
    },
    "confirmed",
    theFilters
  );
```

The notification works; I've tested it and my "Subscription processing triggered.." happens when changes take place in the account.

While this subscription is active, if I call again:

```
let subscriptionId = await userConnection.onProgramAccountChange
```

with another filter but on the same connection, even though I did not unsubscribe from the first subscription, my returned subscriptionId is also 0.

Does anyone know why this might happen? Shouldn't an rpc endpoint support multiple subscriptions?

node is version 17.9.0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP fixed their own problem. If you think that the solution is of general interest to others with whatever problem you had, then modify the question, self-answer your question, and accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does seem to increment the number. I had some other error. Thank you!